# Why Mapbox eachLayer function doesn't fire every time page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

This piece of code gives me some head aches:

```
regions = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('somefile.geojson');
layer.on('ready', function(e) {
     var regionBounds;
     console.log(regions);
     regions.eachLayer(function(lr) { //This function fires about one of two site loads.
         if(lr.feature.properties.title == '{{ $region->name }}') {
             regionBounds = lr.getBounds();
         }
     });

     layer.eachLayer(function(lr) {
         if(lr.feature.geometry.type == 'Point') {
              lr.setIcon(L.divIcon(icon));
         }
     });

     map.fitBounds(regionBounds);
}
```

When `eachLayer()` fails, `regions` _request property is set to XMLHttpRequest, and null when map is loaded properly, but I'm not sure what does it mean. I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure this out, and make this function work on each site load, obviously.

Comment: can you show us a demo site or jsfiddle of this in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `on.('ready', ...)` function isn't connected to `regions`, it's connected to `layer` (which I'm guessing is defined elsewhere). If you change it to `regions.on('ready', ...)` the function won't execute until `somefile.geojson` is loaded and should execute on every page load.

Comment: You're right, I tried earlier this inside layer 'ready' event, but it didn't work. I thought it is possible to add listeners inside other listeners, am I wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your full code -- what is `layer` referring to, and does it ever load such that the other listener would fire?

Comment: Layer is same as regions, just another geojson, and I ment: ```layer.on('ready', function(e) { layer.on('ready', function(...``` Is that a bad practice?

Comment: Would you mind sending along your whole code? It is difficult to debug in a vacuum.